# Redirección cuando GET id no existe

Tags: php, mysqli

Básicamente tengo el siguiente código:

```
> if( isset( $_GET[ 'id' ] ) ) {
     $id = $_GET[ 'id' ];
}
else {
    if (isset($_POST[ 'id'])) {
        $id = $_POST[ 'id' ]; 
     }
    else{ 
    header("Location: page.php");
     }
}


$result = dameUnProyecto($id, $link);

    for( ; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ); )
    {
        $titulo = $row["titulo"];
        $id     = $row["id"];
       ...
```

El problema es que no redirige cuando hay un fallo en el id, por ejemplo, si pongo un id que no existe por ejemplo 45678, la página se muestra vacía como si no hubiera errores en vez de llevar a page.php

Creo que lo que debería hacer es comparar el valor del id con el de la base de datos y si el id recibido en GET no coincide con ninguno de los valores de la tabla que te redirija, pero no estoy seguro de si se hace así.

## **EDIT:**

### El problema es que ahora tanto si el resultado es correcto: `page.php?id=primer-link` como si no `page.php?id=prim32231er-li123nk` en el segundo no sale ningún error más que la página en blanco y quisiera que redireccionara.

He encontrado también este código, pero no lo entiendo muy bien/no sé cómo funciona y al intentar incorporarlo no me ha funcionado:

```
>  #look for articles
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * 
                          FROM articles 
                          WHERE url = '{$_GET['id']}' ");

# if article not found then go back to aritcles list page
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0){
   header('Location: articles_friendly.php');
   die();
  }
else{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
  }
```

## EDIT 2:

Si la URL está mal escrita: `page.php?id=prim32231er-li123nk` en vez de `page.php?id=primer-link`, no muestra ni la alerta 5 ni la 6.

```
//Comprobamos registro en la Base de datos.
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) === 1) {
        //Associamos datos desde la Base de datos.
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("5");</script>';

        $titulo = $row["titulo"];
        $id     = $row["id"];
        $descripcion     = $row["descripcion"];
        $foto   = $row["foto"];
        $friendly_url   = $row["friendly_url"];
        }
    } else { //0 registtros encontrados.
        //Redirección o mensaje articulo no existe en la Base de datos.
        echo '<script>window.location="404.php"</script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("6");</script>';
    }
```

Comment: Podrias poner todo tu codigo?, no entiendo bien si quieres redirigir en el primer y segundo bloque if o despues de que buscas el ID en la base de datos. El header("Location: page.php"); se ve bien, pero ahi solo estas buscando si el usuario envio un id por medio de alguno de los dos metodos post y get.

Comment: Prueba esto: `if( isset( $_GET[ 'id' ] ) ) { $id = $_GET[ 'id' ]; } else { header("Location: page.php"); }` recuerda que tu metodo `$_POST` no va funcionar, ya que estas obteniendo tu valor por el metodo `GET`.

Comment: @D.Bulten la teoría era que está recopilando por GET o POST si existe id y si existe entonces muestra la página, y si no existe de ninguna manera te redirige. Pero esto no solventa el fallo de si ha recibido un valor por alguna de esas dos maneras y ese valor no existe en la base de datos, que también debería redirigir. No sé si me explico.

Comment: @IsmaelMartinez la idea es que si existe id y además coincide con el valor que tiene en la base de datos, que siga la página sin problemas, y que si no, se ejecute la redirección.

Comment: `GET['id]` y `POST['id']` son enteros los dos? Por otro lado, fíjate en tu `WHERE` debes pasar tu variable `$id`, ya que sino tu `POST` no te sirve, algo así: `WHERE url = '$id'`

Comment: @D.Bulten Antes sí eran enteros, pero ya no, está enlazado a la pregunta anterior y ahora es un valor del tipo: mi-url. El WHERE y todo eso es lo que hemos solucionado en el anterior tema y sí que funciona. El problema es que ahora tanto si el resultado es correcto: page.php?id=primer-link como si no page.php?id=prim32231er-li123nk en el segundo no sale ningún error más que la página en blanco y quisiera que redireccionara

Comment: Postea todo el primer fragmento de codigo incluida la funcion dameUnProyecto, asi podriamos ver mejor tu codigo y tu logica. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Un posible ejemplo:**

```
<?php
//Esta definido metodo 'GET'
if ( isset( $_GET[ 'id' ] ) ) {
     $id = filter_var($_GET[ 'id' ], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);//Removemos caracteres ilegales.
} else {
    //Esta definido el metodo 'POST'
    if (isset($_POST[ 'id'])) {
        $id = filter_var($_POST[ 'id' ], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);//Removemos caracteres ilegales.       
    } else {
        header("Location: page.php");
    }
}

//Conexión
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "password", "basedatos");

/* comprobar la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//Sentencia
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE url='$id' LIMIT 1");
//Comprobamos registro en la Base de datos.
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) === 1) {
    //Associamos datos desde la Base de datos.
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        //Salida datos.
        $titulo = $row["titulo"];       
        echo "$titulo";
    }
} else { //0 registtros encontrados.
    //Redirección o mensaje articulo no existe en la Base de datos.
    header("Location: proyectos.php");  
}
?>
```

> **Nota:** te aconsejo por seguridad utilizar sentencias [mysqli prepare](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [PDO.](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) También te aconsejo leer bien
>   [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta D.Bulten! He comprobado tu código y le veo el mismo problema de antes que te he puesto en la respuesta:     El problema es que ahora tanto si el resultado es correcto: page.php?id=primer-link como si no page.php?id=prim32231er-li123nk en el segundo no sale ningún error más que la página en blanco y quisiera que redireccionara.

Comment: Prueba en cambiar tu `header('location')` por `echo '<script>window.location="proyectos.php"</script>';` donde tu sentencia, a veces no redirige `header` porque si se imprime antes cualquier cosa, este no funciona.

Comment: Comprobado y sigue pasando lo mismo. Se ve que si detecta cualquier cosa como dices ya no comprueba si este existe en la base de datos y lo imprime, y si no existe pues no imprime nada pero no redirige si no está en la base de datos que es la idea.

Comment: Incluyo un Edit en el post para responderte.

Comment: Vale, he encontrado el problema, la solución la pongo en una respuesta

Comment: Vale amig@, suerte en tu proyecto, un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, has sido de gran ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo el código de @D.Bulten, solo tenía un fallo:

### El problema:

Si la URL está mal escrita: page.php?id=prim32231er-li123nk en vez de page.php?id=primer-link, no muestra ni la alerta 5 ni la 6.

```
//Comprobamos registro en la Base de datos.
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) === 1) {
    //Associamos datos desde la Base de datos.
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("5");</script>';

    $titulo = $row["titulo"];
    $id     = $row["id"];
    $descripcion     = $row["descripcion"];
    $foto   = $row["foto"];
    $friendly_url   = $row["friendly_url"];
    }
} else { //0 registtros encontrados.
    //Redirección o mensaje articulo no existe en la Base de datos.
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("6");</script>';
    echo '<script>window.location="404.php"</script>';

}
```

### La solución:

Invertimos la pregunta.

```
    //Comprobamos registro en la Base de datos.
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("6");</script>';
        echo '<script>window.location="404.php"</script>';

    } else{ 
        for( ; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ); )
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("5");</script>';

        $titulo = $row["titulo"];
        $id     = $row["id"];
        $descripcion     = $row["descripcion"];
        $foto   = $row["foto"];
        $friendly_url   = $row["friendly_url"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

En caso de que solo quieras redirigir cuando buscas un registro especifico dentro de tu base de datos haz lo siguiente:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){
    header("Location: page.php");
    die();
}
```

Ahi estarias verificando que realmente exista un registro en tu base de datos, de no ser así, rediriges a la pagina que deseas y matas el proceso.

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes unas llaves mñas puestas, salvo que tengas un if antes que no muestra tu codigo, solo deberias de hacer la validacion de esta manera:

```
//Verifico primeramente si la variable fue enviada desde un Formulario o ajax con el metodo post
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    goto a;//Si esta declarada salto a la query de busqueda
};

//Verifico si la variable proviene por medio de url o ajax con el metodo get
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    goto a;//Si esta declarada salto a la query de busqueda
}

a:
$a = $this->query("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id = '$id'");
$cant = $a->num_rows();

if($cant <=0){
    //No existe la ID
    header('location: page.php');
}

//Si existe continuo la ejecución del código *****************

//Informacion sobrfe el operador goto
//http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.goto.php
```

Comment: Hola Carlos, esto no me está arreglando nada. Quería hacer doble comprobación por GET y POST y si no se cumple, redireccionar, que es lo que hace ahora. El problema es que me gustaría que redireccionase también cuando el valor no coincide con ninguno de la base de datos, es decir, por si yo pongo un id numérico por ejemplo 7398 sigue funcionando, aunque este no exista en la base de datos y me gustaría que lo detectara como nulo y redireccionara.

Comment: Primero allí tiene la doble comprobación, es decir si viene por método GET o viene por Método POST, el asunto es que no vas a recibir una petición GET y una POST al mismo tiempo una misma petición, eso no va a pasar, o recibes por medio de url por GET o viene desde un form por POST que es lo que aparece en el código descrito arriba, para lo otro, solo debes realizar una consulta y verificar si arroja resultados, de ser negativo, rediriges al usuario.

Comment: Ya modifique el código, ve si así te sirve más, recuerda que debes escapar la data para proteger tu base de datos